# Have pandas wide_to_long() function consider stub at end of column name rather than beginning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a large dataframe which I need to pivot to long. The dataframe is in this format:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'2010_A(weekly)': np.random.rand(3),
                   '2011_A(weekly)': np.random.rand(3),
                   '2010_B(weekly)': np.random.rand(3),
                   '2011_B(weekly)': np.random.rand(3),
                   'X' : np.random.randint(3, size=3)})
df['id'] = df.index
df
```

If the names were opposite, like this:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A(weekly)_2010': np.random.rand(3),
                   'A(weekly)_2011': np.random.rand(3),
                   'B(weekly)_2010': np.random.rand(3),
                   'B(weekly)_2011': np.random.rand(3),
                   'X' : np.random.randint(3, size=3)})
df['id'] = df.index
df
```

It would be easy to use `wide_to_long` to pivot my table into the desired format like this:

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, ['A(weekly)', 'B(weekly)'], i='id',
                j='year', sep='_')
```

However, I have not found a way to make wide_to_long consider the names backwards.

Is there anyway to use `wide_to_long` in a way where it uses the end of the column to identify the stubname?

The desired output is a 5 column long dataframe with column names being `"id", "year", "X", "A(weekly)", "B(weekly)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with `pd.wide_to_long`. You have to use other methods or rename columns to swap fields:

```
>>> pd.wide_to_long(df.rename(columns=lambda x: '_'.join(x.split('_')[::-1])), 
                    ['A(weekly)', 'B(weekly)'], i='id', j='year', sep='_')

         X  A(weekly)  B(weekly)
id year                         
0  2010  0   0.548814   0.437587
1  2010  1   0.715189   0.891773
2  2010  1   0.602763   0.963663
0  2011  0   0.544883   0.383442
1  2011  1   0.423655   0.791725
2  2011  1   0.645894   0.528895
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjnanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) - for this particular use case use a `.value` placeholder to represent the stub (the column you wish to remain as a header), and use `names_sep` to split the columns based on a separator:

```py
# pip insall pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index = ['X', 'id'], names_to = ('year', '.value'), names_sep = '_')
   X  id  year  A(weekly)  B(weekly)
0  0   0  2010   0.548814   0.437587
1  1   1  2010   0.715189   0.891773
2  1   2  2010   0.602763   0.963663
3  0   0  2011   0.544883   0.383442
4  1   1  2011   0.423655   0.791725
5  1   2  2011   0.645894   0.528895
```